# TCP Server not receiving properly when data is dynamicaly typed

Tags: c#, tcp, .net-4.0, tcpclient, networkstream

I am working on what should be a simple TCP server application that receives data from a stream and stores it in a list.

I have succeeded in getting the data when it is sent in one message per connection. My problem seems to be when testing it using telnet from the command line. I will start to type and the program will grab one or two characters depending on my typing speed and then won't receive anything from that stream again. I really am at a loss for why. If I put a thread.sleep in the stream.DataAvailable loop then it will get a few more characters but again will stop. Any help is appreciated. My class is as follows:

```
public class TCPServer
{
    private TcpListener listener;

    public List<string> messages;

    public TCPServer(IPAddress ip, int port)
    {
        try
        {
            messages = new List<string>();

            listener = new TcpListener(ip, port);
            listener.Start();

            listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(ClientConnected, listener);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void ClientConnected(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

        TcpClient client;
        try
        {
            client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            string message = "";

            while (!stream.DataAvailable)
            {
            }

            while (stream.DataAvailable)
            {                 
                byte[] readBytes = new byte[65536];
                stream.Read(readBytes, 0, readBytes.Length);
                message += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBytes).TrimEnd('\0');
            }

            if (message != null)
            {
                messages.Add(message);
                message = "";
            }
            listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(ClientConnected, listener);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        listener.Stop();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve this problem by looking more into the NetworkStream class. In the callback from BeginReceiveTcpClient I extracted the network stream from the tcpclient so I could access the BeginReceive async method. The relevant code is below:

```
 private void ClientConnected(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        byte[] readBytes = new byte[65536];

        TcpClient client;
        try
        {
            client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, ReadStream, stream);

            listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(ClientConnected, listener);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void ReadStream(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {

            NetworkStream stream = (NetworkStream)ar.AsyncState;
            int bytesRead = stream.EndRead(ar);

            content += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            dataProcessor.ProcessData(messages);
            stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, ReadStream, stream);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The reading loop is highly incorrect.

You misunderstand that `DataAvailable` does not tell you how many bytes will arrive. It gives you a lower bound and might say 0 at any time. The loop will abort early. Using `DataAvailable` is almost always incorrect.

This accomplishes nothing and is a busy wait which should raise a red flag with you:

```
        while (!stream.DataAvailable)
        {
        }
```

The right way to read is to simply call `Read`. You need to use the return value from `Read` to see how many bytes have arrived. Trimming zeroes is incorrect (you can't receive zeroes that way) and a hack that, again, should raise a mental red flag! This can't be the right way to do it.

Sockets are very hard to get right. Don't make suspicious hacks, that only increase the chance of non-deterministic failures.

Comment: If that isn't the right way to do it (which I do believe) can you show the right way? This didn't really answer the question.

Comment: Well, it answers why it's not working. You probably should try setting up a read loop. If your protocol is line based you can try StreamReader.ReadLine. Search the web for a socket tutorial (that does not contain the word DataAvailable :) ). There is no need to repeat that content here.

Comment: DataAvailable is a Boolean in NetworkStreams, not an Integer value, usr. So checking if it's true or false will most definitely work. The OP never even used it in the context of checking how many bytes to receive. There is a difference between `Socket.DataAvailable` and `NetworkStream.DataAvailable`.

Comment: It might wrongly return false causing you to stop reading. If you're testing against zero the bool and int versions are equivalent. If you understand the issue, and I'm not sure you do, you will see that his reading loop might erroneously abort early. Depending on what exactly you're doing it might be safe, but always unnecessary, to check DataAvailable. Depending on network speed and timing you might also get away with it and not see failures except very rarely. You could call that lucky, I'd call it unlucky because the bug is there and will *eventually* strike. @VisualVincent

Comment: I've sent 700 MB files using an application that checks `NetworkStream.DataAvailable` and all data has been sent and received properly ;). Also, according to the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.available(v=vs.110).aspx) `Socket.DataAvailable` actually does indicate how much data is _currently_ available to read (that has been queued in the network buffer). So it won't indicate all data, but the data it has at the moment. So I don't understand why `Socket.DataAvailable` would be bad to use?

Comment: Okay I see what you mean, I just reacted to it since you always seem to disapprove using `DataAvailable`. Well I use length-prefixing for my communication, so I must be doing it the safe/proper way. :)

Comment: @VisualVincent clarification: If I were to search for `DataAvailable` in posts  on this site, 99% of them would be broken code. I know of only one esoteric valid use case for that property.